# Cant resolve hostnames except using nslookup/dig in CentOS [resolved]

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking

I am unable to resolve hostnames, except using dig/nslookup.  Declaring hosts in `/etc/hosts` works fine.  DNSmasq nor bind is running.  Below is the output of `tcpdump port 53` when running `dig google.com`:

```
21:02:49.269083 IP txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.39872 > dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxs.com.domain:  7362+ A? google.com. (28)
21:02:49.269614 IP dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain > txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.39872:  7362 5/0/0 A ord08s07-in-f19.1e100.net,[|domain]
21:02:49.270506 IP txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.33316 > dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain:  30910+ PTR? 83.225.125.74.in-addr.arpa. (44)
21:02:49.303321 IP dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain > txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.33316:  30910*- 1/0/0 (83)
```

And the results while running `ping google.com`:

```
21:03:05.027197 IP txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.59151 > dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain:  56092+ A? google.com. (28)
21:03:05.029069 IP dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain > txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.59151:  56092 5/0/0 A ord08s07-in-f18.1e100.net,[|domain]
21:03:05.029309 IP txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.58238 > dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain:  10345+ PTR? 82.225.125.74.in-addr.arpa. (44)
21:03:05.065058 IP dxxxxxx3.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.domain > txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com.58238:  10345*- 1/0/0 (83)
```

Ping does not return any packets when used with hostnames.  The results above are delayed ~5 seconds from when the command is given.  I have no trouble pinging IPs.

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.100.52.11
nameserver 10.100.52.13
```

Both name servers give good results when used with dig.

Results of `route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.xxx.131.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.xxx.131.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
10.xxx.131.xxx      txxxxxx1.corp.mxxxxxxs.com ast01
10.xxx.32.xxx       mail.mxxxxxxs.com
```

SSHD does not even allow logins if `UseDNS` is set to yes.  NSCD is running: `nscd     28525  0.0  0.0 233652  2900 ?        Ssl  20:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/nscd`.

Thanks!

**. . . EDIT**

I resolved this.  `/etc/nsswitch.conf` had the line:

`hosts:      files wins dns`

I changed it to read:

`hosts:      dns files wins`

and everything works now.  What's bizarre is that things were working fine up until last week.  Nothing changed, certainly not as far as DNS.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This also affects ubuntu when the setup is `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

Comment: Having similar issue for some specific domains only.

Answer (score 1):

Are you relying on hostname completion (or "dns suffix appending" in the Windows world) to get a Fully Qualified Domain Name when you're running ping? If so, your `/etc/resolv.conf` is missing the `domain` and/or `search` options.

```
nameserver 10.100.52.11
nameserver 10.100.52.13
domain corp.mxxxxxxs.com
```

This should automatically append corp.mxxxxxxs.com to $HOST so you have a FQDN that correctly resolves.

See the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) for more details.

Comment: I was never before, and had no problems, but it does seem like that would've fixed things.  I'll test with the previous nsswitch.conf and a search option set to see what happens.